# searchkick is called more than once in model error when running rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, rspec, searchkick

I am getting this error:

/Users/Jiji/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/searchkick-1.3.0/lib/searchkick/model.rb:6:in `searchkick': Only call searchkick once per model (RuntimeError)

when running rspec tests, don't know why i only called 'searchkick' in my user model once. All other models are fine but there is something wrong in the user model

Comment: i have a similar error but in my case was that i had 'searchkick' twice in the model. do you have the backtrace?